# Trying to display a message when the shopping cart is empty

Tags: php, sql, arrays, if-statement

I created a shopping cart using an array. I'm trying to output a "Your cart is empty." message when the array is empty. It does not seem to work for me when i try this...

```
<?php 
            if (isset($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])):
            if (count($_SESSION['shopping_cart']) < 1):
         ?>
            <a>Your cart is empty.</a>

         <?php endif; endif; ?>

<?php 
            if (isset($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])):
            if (count($_SESSION['shopping_cart']) > 0):
         ?>
            <a href="checkout.php" class="check-button">Checkout</a>

         <?php endif; endif; ?>
```

Comment: Please echo `$_SESSION['shopping_cart']` and show the output here

Answer (score 0):

Use `empty()` instead of `isset`

```
<?php if (empty($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])): ?>

<a>Your cart is empty.</a>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( ! empty($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])):?>

<a href="checkout.php" class="check-button">Checkout</a>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: i just tried it and im still not getting any text output when the array is empty.

Comment: Try to `var_dump($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])` and post the result here. If there is no result add your code where you initialize the `$_SESSION['shopping_cart']`